# How to find attribute without value is present or not in HTML tag using Selenium?

Tags: java, html, selenium, attributes

Ex: Radio - checked

```
<input id="rdo" type="radio" name="nrdo" value="1" checked>
```

Ex: Radio - unchecked

```
<input id="rdo" type="radio" name="nrdo" value="1">
```

Need to find attribute without value is present on HTML tag or not using Selenium.

This code works only if attribute has value:

```java
public boolean isAttribtuePresent(String element, String attribute) { 
    Boolean result = false; 
    String value = "vvv"; 
    // element = "Month ''May'' @xpath=//button[text()='Jun']"; 
    try { 
        value = webElement.getAttribute(attribute); 
        if (value != null) { 
            result = true; 
        } 
    } catch (Exception e) {  
        System.out.print(e.toString()); 
    } 
    System.out.print("***"+value+"*****"); 
    return result; 
}
```

Comment: Can you consider sharing your work with us? Thanks

Comment: Please don't (mis)use comments section to post the code instead of the [edit] your question post it there.

Answer (score 2):

Just check if attributre value is not null.

```js
const hasAttr = (el, attr) => el.getAttribute(attr) != null

console.log(hasAttr(rdo, 'checked'))
console.log(hasAttr(rdo2, 'checked'))
```

```html
<input id="rdo" type="radio" name="nrdo" value="1" checked>
<input id="rdo2" type="radio" name="nrdo" value="1">
```

Answer (score 0):

The element.getAttribute(attributeName) returns null for both
1. Attribute without value
2. Attribute is not present

Answer (score -2):

Use Jquery attr

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

```
$.each($( ":input" ),function(i,o){
 alert($(this).attr("value")==undefined);
})
```

Comment: The question is about Selenium. Using jQuery for this purpose is unachievable.